# Carrying part of a line to the following line Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script that pulls holidays using Invoke-WebRequest and on four of the dates it combines the holidays like so:

```
November 26 and 27
December 24 and 25
```

What I'm trying to do (with little success) is to carry over the month and split those dates so show up like:

```
November 26
November 27
December 24
December 25
```

Is it possible to do this?  I don't want to hard code the month since it's possible in the future that other holidays in different months could do the same thing.

Comment: Is it always either 1 or 2 dates per line? If not, is `and` always the separator, or could you expect `January 1, 2, 3 and 4` for example?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - With the current set I'm working with it's always 1 or 2 dates per line and the separator is `and`.  That being said it is possible there could be more in the future, but in my use case I doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use regular expressions:

```
$inputString = "November 24 and 25"
$pattern = '^(\p{L}+) (\d+)(?: and (\d+))?'

if($inputString -match $pattern){
  # if the -match operator found a match, it populates the `$Matches` variable
  $Matches[1,2] -join " "
  if($Matches.ContainsKey(3)){
    # the second group of digits was found, output the corresponding date string too
    $Matches[1,3] -join " "
  }
}
```

The regular expression pattern used above describes:

```
^            # Start of string anchor
(\p{L}+)     # Capture group matching 1 or more letters, for the month name
(\d+)        # Capture group matching 1 or more digits, for the first date
(?:          # Start of a non-capturing group
 and (\d+)   # Match literal string ` and ` followed by a capture group matching 1 or more digits
)?           # End of non-capturing group, which the trailing `?` marks "optional"
```

Since the last group matching `and` and capturing the second date is *optional*, the `-match` operator will return true for both formats, and we simply inspect `$Matches` to figure out if a second date was matched and captured or not

Comment: The power of regex at work!  Thank you for the help @MathiasR.Jessen!  That is just what I was looking for.